# pygame: How would I shade/blit a non-rectangular section of an image?

Tags: pygame, blit

So I know how to shade an image. And I know how to blit a rectangular section of an image. But what about, say, a triangle? Or a trapezoid?  (e.g. https://i.stack.imgur.com/WwRBG.png)

Answer (score 0):

A minute after I asked this, I figured out how to shade, at least. Isn't that always the way?

Anyway, it basically comes down to something as simple as:

```
surface.blit(image, pos, area)
pygame.draw.polygon(surface, (0,0,0,128), pointlist, 0)
```

where 128 is whatever alpha value you want and pointlist is a list of the vertices around the section you want.